# Methods and Variable

Tags: vba, excel

Is it possible to use varibles within a VBA method?

For eg, i'm trying to add item to a list: Listbox**1**.AddItem (item1)

Qns: Am I able to replace "1" with a varible: Listbox & **"Varible"**.AddItem (item1)

```
Sub ThisWorks()
Worksheets("Control Sheet").Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA.AddItem ("Remark1")
End Sub
=======================
Sub test()
'Trying to use this as a varible instead
X = "Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA"
Worksheets("Control Sheet").X.AddItem ("Remark1")
'Error 438: Object does not support this property or method
End Sub
=======================
Sub testarr()
Dim y(0 To 2)

Set y(0) = "Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA"
Worksheets("Control Sheet").y(0).AddItem ("Remark1")
'Error 438: Object does not support this property or method
End Sub
```

Comment: Certainly, yes. Post some code and we might be able to point out precisely where the issues are.

Comment: Hi Matt, thanks for your reply, can you take a look?
==============
Sub ThisWorks()

Worksheets("Control Sheet").Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA.AddItem ("Remark1")

End Sub
==============   
   
Sub testarr()

Dim y(0 To 2)
Set y(0) = "Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA"

Worksheets("Control Sheet").y(0).AddItem ("Remark1")

End Sub

==============
Sub test()

'Trying to use this as a varible instead
X = "Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA"

Worksheets("Control Sheet").X.AddItem ("Remark1")
'Error 438: Object does not support this property or method

End Sub

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that any way to use `INDIRECT` variable names in VBA would be possible.

One workaround is to define arrays and refer to their items, e.g.:

```
Dim ListBoxes(10) as Variable

Set ListBoxes(1) = ListBox1
Set ListBoxes(2) = ListBox2
(instead of preparing the array manually you can 
    also add the items programmatically to the form)
...

ListBoxes(i).AddItem(item1)
```

Comment: Hi Mate, thanks for your reply.
I tried it out, but don't seem to be able to get it to work.
I've added a snippet of my code to my qns.
Can you kindly take a look?

Answer (score 0):

You'd need to loop the controls in the appropriate container to check if its name equals the control name you need. I.e.

```
For Each c in Controls
    If LCase(c.Name) = LCase("NameOfDesiredControl") Then
        ... Work with it ...
    End If
Next
```

This can easily be translated into a function.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what your goals are, but the following modifications to your posted code allows it to work:

```
Option Explicit

Sub ThisWorks()
Worksheets("Control Sheet").Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA.AddItem ("Remark1")
End Sub
'=======================
Sub test()
Dim X As Object
'Trying to use this as a varible instead
Set X = Worksheets("Control Sheet").Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA
X.AddItem ("Remark1")

End Sub
'=======================
Sub testarr()
Dim y(0 To 2)

Set y(0) = Worksheets("Control Sheet").Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA
y(0).AddItem ("Remarkx")
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Ron! Thanks very much for sharing!

I'm basically trying to set <Tx_TgtRaw_FX_*Country*> as a varible, as I have a listbox each for 3 countries: US, CA & SG

I ran into issues when I try to set <Tx_TgtRaw_FX_CA> as a varible itself.

ie. Worksheets("Control Sheet").*Varible*.AddItem ("Remark1") will not run

Comment: @ChristopherTeoh How about a Collection of objects with the CountryCode as the key?

Comment: Sounds good! I've not have experience creating a collection. Do you mind to give an example?

Comment: @ChristopherTeoh Probably you'll be best off with the method used in `testarr`